# Unable to add DSS to a signed PDF after reloading it

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature

As per my current understanding, it is not allowed to add `DSS` for Timestamp Certificates while signing a PDF(in case of signature timestamp). So, I am trying to first sign the PDF, save it, and then reload it as `PDDocument` to add `DSS` for Timestamp Certificates.

Below is my source code for the same:

```
//This saves the signed file to responseStream
ByteArrayInputStream responseStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());

//Reloads output PDF as PDDocument to embed DSS for TSA Certificates
PDDocument documentForLTV = PDDocument.load(responseStream);

//New response stream with DSS
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStreamLTV = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

//Adds revocation info and certs for TSA into DSS of PDDocument 
addValidationInformation(documentForLTV, TSACertificates);

documentForLTV.saveIncremental(outputStreamLTV);

//Checking updated DSS. Updated DSS shows TSA certs which are expected to be added.
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = documentForLTV.getDocumentCatalog();
COSDictionary catalog = docCatalog.getCOSObject();
COSDictionary dss = validationService.getOrCreateDictionaryEntry(COSDictionary.class, catalog, "DSS");
COSArray certs = validationService.getOrCreateDictionaryEntry(COSArray.class, dss, "Certs");

//final output response. This  outputStreamLTV does not contain the TSA Certs and revocation info.
ByteArrayInputStream responseStreamLTV = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStreamLTV.toByteArray());

documentForLTV.close();
return responseStreamLTV;
```

Here, I am adding Timestamp Certs and Revocation Information to DSS using my method `addValidationInformation`. This is the same method, which I use to add Validation information for signing Certs to `DSS`. And while debugging, I can see it successfully adds the timestamp certificates to DSS. But I can't find them in my final output PDF.
`outputStreamLTV` only contains Validation Information for Signing Certs.

addValidationInformation method is as follows:

```
public void addValidationInformation(PDDocument document, Certificate[] certificateChain) {

        List<String> ocspResponse = getOcspData(certificateChain);
        List<String> crlResponse = getClrData(certificateChain);
        List<String> certificates = getCertificates(certificateChain);

        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
        COSDictionary catalog = docCatalog.getCOSObject();
        catalog.setNeedsTobeUpdated(true);
        // As mentioned in PDFBox Samples
        COSDictionary dss = getOrCreateDictionaryEntry(COSDictionary.class, catalog, "DSS");
        dss.setNeedsTobeUpdated(true);
        COSDictionary vri = getOrCreateDictionaryEntry(COSDictionary.class, dss, "VRI");
        vri.setNeedsTobeUpdated(true);
        COSArray ocsps = getOrCreateDictionaryEntry(COSArray.class, dss, "OCSPs");
        ocsps.setNeedsTobeUpdated(true);
        COSArray crls = getOrCreateDictionaryEntry(COSArray.class, dss, "CRLs");
        crls.setNeedsTobeUpdated(true);
        COSArray certs = getOrCreateDictionaryEntry(COSArray.class, dss, "Certs");
        certs.setNeedsTobeUpdated(true);

        if (ocspResponse != null) {
            ocspResponse.forEach(ocsp -> {
                byte[] ocspData = b64Decoder.decode(ocsp);
                try {
                    ocsps.add(writeDataToStream(ocspData, document));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }

        if (!ocspResponse.isEmpty()) {
            vri.setItem("OCSP", ocsps);
        }

        //Same for CRL and Certs...

    }
```

Some of my other findings are:

1. I am able to add timestamp certs and revocation information in similar way using PDFBox samples `AddValidationInformation` and [this](https://github.com/ETDA/PDFTimestamping/blob/52bf0f1f77626fb0f4c6d4103bcd461515f74430/src/main/java/CreateSignedTimeStamp.java#L183) method. But I prefer to use my current implementation since that sample is not exactly fitting as per my requirements. Also, they will add duplicate code for same functionality.
2. Also, i use `PDDocument.save(outputStreamLTV)` instead of `PDDocument.saveIncremental(outputStreamLTV)`. Output PDF shows desired DSS but the signature gets invalid.

Kindly suggest how can I make my existing code work and what am I missing? It seems there is some issue while saving the PDDocument to stream.
Or is it a bug at `PDFBox` side, because I am able to add DSS using the same method `addValidationInformation` before signature using one dummy call to TSA for fetching certs.

Comment: @mkl , any suggestions please.

Comment: What does your `addValidationInformation` do exactly? In particular, does it ensure a path of objects marked `NeedToBeUpdated` exists from the trailer to the updated objects?

Comment: @mkl I have updated the above description to include the `addValidationInformation` method. Also, I tried setting `dss`, `vri`, `ocsps`, 'crls', `certs`  as `NeedToBeUpdated`. It still not worked. It worked when I called this method before signature with same set of certificates.

Comment: From the current code, you're woring on a closed file here: `documentForLTV.close();

//Checking updated DSS. Updated DSS shows TSA certs which are expected to be added.
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = documentForLTV.getDocumentCatalog();`

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Issue won't resolve even if I close the document later on. Updated the source code.

Comment: It seems, it is a bug at PDFBox side, because if I use `PDDocument.save` instead of `saveIncremental`, DSS is present in output document but the signature gets invalidated. @mkl

Comment: I don't see your code setting the `NeedToBeUpdated` flags anywhere. `saveIncremental` needs those flags to work, `save` doesn't. Thus, i think the issue is not a pdfbox but but the missing `NeedToBeUpdated` management in your code.

Comment: You can't do this. Adding, subtracting, or changing data in the signed object is going to invalidate the signature. This is a fact of life. You will have to find a way to incorporate the timestamp into the digital signature process.

Comment: Thanks @mkl It worked. I missed making catalog as NeedsToBeUpdated.

Comment: The `AddValidationInformation.java` example from PDFBox had that.

Comment: @user207421 *"You can't do this."* - you may want to read up on integrated pdf signatures and incremental updates.